# How to upgrade aurelia build from webpack1 to webpack3?

Tags: javascript, webpack, aurelia, babeljs

When I try to upgrade the javascript libraries in the package.json file, and updated the web.configi.js to conform to the new webpack configuration in 3.4.1, it didn't work. Many of the files are not being written to the output like they were with webpack1.

I opened an issue on github for the extract-text-webpack-plugin.
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/600

I was told this would be a better place to ask.

Here is the webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var AureliaWebpackPlugin = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

var config = require('./project.build.config.js');

var filesToCopy = [];

//create list of index.html files to be copied to wwwroot
config.apps.forEach(app => {
  filesToCopy.push({ from: app.src + '.html', to: config.outDir + app.dest });
});

config.assets.forEach(asset => {
  filesToCopy.push(asset);
});


var plugins = [

  new CleanPlugin(config.outDir),

  new AureliaWebpackPlugin.AureliaPlugin({ aureliaApp: undefined }),

  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: "commons",
    // (the commons chunk name)

    filename: "commons.js",
    // (the filename of the commons chunk)

    minChunks: 3,
    // (Modules must be shared between 3 entries)

    // chunks: ["pageA", "pageB"],
    // (Only use these entries)
  }),

  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'commons',
    filename: 'commons.js'
  }),

  new ExtractTextPlugin({
    disable: false,
    filename: '[name].css',
    allChunks: true
  }),

  new CopyWebpackPlugin(filesToCopy, { copyUnmodified: false }),

  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
  }),
];

// create the apps entry points
var entryPoints = {};
config.apps.forEach(app => {
  entryPoints[app.name] = ['materialize-loader!./materialize.config.js', 'babel-polyfill', 'whatwg-fetch', 'aurelia-bootstrapper'];
});

var webpackBaseConfig = {

  entry: entryPoints,

  output: {
    path: config.outDir,
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  plugins: plugins,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    alias: {
      '$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'),
      'jquery': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
    }
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/i,
        loaders: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: [
            ['env', { loose: true, modules: true }]
          ],
          plugins: ['transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.html?$/i,
        use: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
      }, {
        test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
      }, {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
      }, {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "file-loader"
      }, {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
      }, {
        test: /\.(png|gif|jpe|ico)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000'
      }
    ]
  },
};

module.exports = webpackBaseConfig;
```

This what packages are installed

```
      "aurelia": {
    "build": {
      "moduleRootOverride": {
        "aurelia-templating-resources": "dist/commonjs"
      },
      "resources": [
        "aurelia-validation/validate-binding-behavior",
        "aurelia-validation/validation-errors-custom-attribute",
        "aurelia-validation/validation-renderer-custom-attribute",
        "aurelia-dialog",
        "aurelia-validation"
      ]
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aurelia-loader-nodejs": "1.0.1",
    "aurelia-pal-nodejs": "1.0.0-beta.1.0.0",
    "aurelia-protractor-plugin": "1.0.5",
    "aurelia-testing": "1.0.0-beta.3.0.1",
    "aurelia-tools": "1.0.0",
    "aurelia-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "4.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "1.3.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "5.0.4",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "eslint": "4.4.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "http-server": "0.10.0",
    "ip": "1.1.5",
    "isparta": "4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "jest-cli": "20.0.4",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "2.2.3",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.4",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "nps": "5.7.0",
    "nps-utils": "1.3.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "replace": "0.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "strip-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "wait-on": "2.0.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.6.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.5.0",
    "webpack-shell-plugin": "0.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "^2.1.1",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper-webpack": "1.1.0",
    "aurelia-dialog":"1.0.0-rc.1.0.3",
    "aurelia-event-aggregator":"1.0.1",
    "aurelia-fetch-client":"1.1.2",
    "aurelia-framework":"1.1.4",
    "aurelia-history-browser":"1.0.0",
    "aurelia-loader-webpack":"2.1.0",
    "aurelia-logging-console":"1.0.0",
    "aurelia-materialize-bridge":"0.30.0",
    "aurelia-pal-browser":"1.2.1",
    "aurelia-polyfills":"1.2.2",
    "aurelia-route-recognizer":"1.1.0",
    "aurelia-router":"1.3.0",
    "aurelia-templating-binding":"1.3.0",
    "aurelia-templating-resources":"1.4.0",
    "aurelia-templating-router":"1.1.0",
    "aurelia-validation":"1.1.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "get-ip": "^1.2.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.0",
    "material-design-icons":"3.0.1",
    "materialize-css":"0.100.1",
    "materialize-loader":"2.0.1",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "numeral": "2.0.6",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Edited to show what packages are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [cli](https://github.com/aurelia/cli), create a new project and copy in the package.json to your project. Then the webpack configuration should be a guide for you as well.